# Nuget won't install package, due to a mismatch in the targeted framework

Tags: python, c#, .net, nuget

I have a C# project that references the `python` package. This project was developed in Visual Studio 2017, and targeted .NET 4.5.2. I am now updating the project, targeting .NET 4.7.2. I also want to update the `python` package to a later version (one which has Python 3.9 and not Python 3.5).

When I try to update the package. I get an error saying the package can't be installed in a project that targets .NET 4.7.2, because it doesn't reference any .NET 4.7.2 assemblies or content.

So it's quite obvious I can't use .NET 4.7.2 with this package. The question is - which version of .NET *can* I use with this package? How can I tell which .NET framework a Nuget package supports?

Comment: Do you mean this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/python/3.9.9? It's weird that it wouldn't work, since it has no dependencies on any framework version

Comment: Yes, this one. And yet, it won't install :-(

Comment: Does it also fail if you manually update the csproj to the version you want? Sometimes, VS' Package Manager fails for random reasons and gives weird error messages

Comment: Did you change your csproj from old-style to SDK-style, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start off going to the package page on nuget.org, as posted in the comments to your question: https://www.nuget.org/packages/python/3.9.9

On the right hand side, there's a link called "Open in NuGet Package Explorer" which will take you here: https://nuget.info/packages/python/3.9.9

This lets you inspect the contents of the package.

Now, you need some knowledge of how NuGet works, but of the 3 top level folders in the package, only `build/` matches a NuGet convention. The only file under here is `build/native/python.props`, which matches [NuGet's convention of `build/{tfm}/{packageid}.[props|targets]`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/9187a50daec29061772a2057490697c6c0e4c354/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/ContentModel/ManagedCodeConventions.cs#L495).

Therefore, this package is only compatible with the `native` TFM, which are C++, not .NET, projects.